# Add list of words at the end of the 1st line in a loop

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list with the names of several files:

```
file1
file2
```

I would like to add at the end of the 1st line of each file the name of the file e.g.:

file 1 first row will be

```
> ATCGCCfile1
```

file 2 first row will be

```
> ATTTCCfile2
```

My idea is now to create a variable a with the file names' name:

`a="file1 file2"`

loop over the files and add the word re-calling the index:

`for i in $a; do cat $i | awk '{print $0"$i"}' > $i.extended_word.txt; done`

however in the output the `awk '{print $0"$i"}'` does not work and gives me just the $i without the name of the file e.g. in case of the 1st file `>ATCGCC$i` .

What am i doing wrong? I also tried the parentesis ( `awk '{print $0"${i}"}'`) but without succeed.

Comment: Do all your files have just one sequence or can you have more lines starting with `>`? Do you always have a space after the `>`? That isn't standard, or required by the fasta format. More importantly, how many files do you have? Do you even need a loop? If you do, can we just do `for f in *` and get all the files of interest, or should that be `for f in *fa` or something else? Can you show us the output of `ls` in the target directory and tell us what files should be modified?

Comment: all files have two rows, it is a fasta file yes. It starts the first line wit the > and the second does not have the >. I would like to modify only the first line.

Comment: OK, and how many files? You really don't want to use a variable, so please show us the output of `ls` in the directory with your files and indicate which ones should be changed. Can we just do `for file in *fa; do...` to get all files? And where does the `ATTTCC` come from? Do you want us to add something from the sequence line or the ID line? Can you show us an example file?

Comment: I have corrected the post adding `file2` is supposed to be `ATTTCCfile2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store a list, you want an array:

```bash
a=(
  file1
  file2
  'other file with spaces'
  $'even with\nnewlines'
)
awk -- '
  FNR == 1 {
    close(out)
    $0 = $0 FILENAME
    out = FILENAME".extended_word.txt"
  }
  {print > out}' "${a[@]}"
```

Beware that if file names contain `=` characters, you'd need to make sure that what's left of the `=` is not a valid `awk` variable. For instance, if you have a `file=1` file, make it `./file=1`.

With GNU `awk`, a work around is to write it:

```bash
gawk -e '
  FNR == 1 {$0 = $0 FILENAME}
  {print > FILENAME ".extended_word.txt"}
  ' -E /dev/null "${a[@]}"
```

Which works even for files with `=` in their path but unfortunately still not for a file called `-`.

Comment: all files have two rows and each file is a fasta file. It starts the first row wit the > and the second does not have the >. I would like to modify only the first row. This approach modify also the second row but works..

Comment: @fusion.slope see edit. I had missed that part of the requirement.

Comment: `print > FILENAME ".extended_word.txt"` is undefined behavior per POSIX (any expression on the right side of in/out redirection needs to be inside parens), it needs to be `print > (FILENAME ".extended_word.txt")` for the syntax to be portable, and you need to close the output files as you go (e.g. at the start of every `FNR==1` section close the previous output file) to avoid a "too many open files" error if you cross some threshold. Once you make those changes it could be written more concisely as `FNR == 1 { close(out); out=FILENAME ".extended_word.txt"; $0 = $0 FILENAME}
  {print > out}'`

Comment: gawk does work around both of those issues I mentioned but it slows down as your number of open output files increases so it's still worth closing them as you go if it's easy to do as in this case.

Comment: @EdMorton, I know that some awk implementations don't like it (OpenBSD's IIRC?) but I can't find the POSIX text that makes it undefined. The grammar specification at least would make that valid. In any case, I've included your improvements, thanks.

Comment: IIRC In a previous incarnation POSIX used to refer to both in and out redirection, now it doesn't mention output but for input does say that related to getline. I'll see if I can find that reference. Meanwhile - there's lots of questions here and on SO asking why `print > "foo" "bar"` produces a syntax error so even without digging up the spec we can see that it's a real problem.

Comment: Take a look at the example above `Since in most cases such constructs are not (or at least should not) be used (because they have a natural ambiguity for which there is no conventional parsing), the meaning of these constructs has been made explicitly unspecified.` in [the POSIX awk spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) to see the input redirection part I mentioned was still in the spec.

Comment: and there's an example question related to the output redirection issue at https://stackoverflow.com/q/21093626/1745001.

Comment: That refers to `getline` though. For `print`, that's still fine in [susv3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) and [susv2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/awk.html) (1997). I'd say those implementations where it doesn't work are non-compliant.

Comment: Right, I said that only refers to redirected input with getline. I'll see if I can dig up the text I recall that says input or output redirection from/to an expression has to be parenthesized without spending too much time googling. It's not obvious to me why `print > "foo" "bar"` is any less ambiguous than `getline < "foo" "bar"` though and so I'd expect any caveats for one to also apply to the other anyway.

Comment: Well, given how much time I'm willing to spend looking for it, I can't find that statement I remember from long ago that an expression on the right side of input **or output** redirection has to be parenthesized. Obviously the problem does exist in some awks so I may just change my usual "is undefined" blurb to "fails in some awks" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the files are in the same directory and the list is in a file:

files.txt

```
file1
file2
```

Using `mapfile` and `sed`:

```bash
mapfile -t files < files.txt

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  if [ ! -f "$f" ]; then
    echo "File '$f' does not exists."
    continue
  fi
  
  sed "1s;.*;&$f;" "$f"
  
  # With option '-i' the file will be written
  # sed -i "1s;.*;&$f;" "$f"
done
```

Comment: Worth noting that the file paths cannot contain `&`, `;`, newline nor backslash characters, and with GNU or busybox `sed` at least cannot start with `-`. (with possibly nasty consequences if they do).